# How to add to Mapbox GL JS ArcGIS Map Service REST API

Tags: mapbox, web-service, rest, gl

I am working on adding an ArcGIS Map Service to an automatically built map by QGIS2Web plugin for the web using MapBox GL JS. I would like to find a resource or snippet that actually works for creating the map REST API layer on the map and it has an error each time I try to build it from the plugin unless I use local layers. I tried adding it by using artificial intelligence but none of those solutions worked for me embedding a call for the service from the HTML script elements. 1. I am looking for a way to build a remote connection to ArcGIS Map Sevice with MapBox GL JS 2. Modify the plugin's automated product to add it if possible

Without the REST layer, I can add some points just fine, but I need the other service layers to add context from Federal data and those data could be updated at anytime.

I get a folder tree that looks like this that allows you to search the map with the index.html:

[image]

While trying to compile a REST API layer:
I get a Python error where the exporter searches for a path to the TEMP directory for the REST service API layer, but it isn't located where the exporter expects it to be.

My thoughts on solving this were:

Find a way to locate a temp REST service object if possible on my client side and see if I can pass it to a new path and let the exporter locate it. However, it appears to be all directly from the REST service URL, there doesn't seem to be a intermediate step for the layer to be built on the client temporarily to locate or I need to better understand how to rewrite my path options for ArcGIS service on QGIS.
-If someone knows how to work around this would be helpful!
Build a raster layer, then try to edit the source code myself in javascript, reroute the raster object to the API URL instead. But I think this will not work because the REST service isn't just a standard local object to compile, it needs intermediate steps to build the object data from the server then add it from what I think is geoJSON.
Here's the error I have:
An error has occurred while executing Python code:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Local\Temp\ProtectedAreasDatabaseoftheUnitedStatesPADUSv3001701282171_piped.tif'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 419, in exportRaster
processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", warpArgs)
File "C:\PROGRA1/QGIS311.15/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 108, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:\PROGRA1/QGIS311.15/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 168, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Unable to execute algorithm
Could not load source layer for INPUT: C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Local\Temp\ProtectedAreasDatabaseoftheUnitedStatesPADUSv3001701282171_piped.tif not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\qgis2web.py", line 59, in run
self.dlg = MainDialog(self.iface)
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 159, in init
self.autoUpdatePreview()
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 334, in autoUpdatePreview
self.previewMap()
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 337, in previewMap
preview_file = self.createPreview()
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 299, in createPreview
return writer.write(self.iface,
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 81, in write
self.preview_file = self.writeOL(iface, feedback,
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\olwriter.py", line 130, in writeOL
exportLayers(iface, layers, folder, precision, optimize,
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 237, in exportLayers
exportRaster(layer, count, layersFolder, feedback, iface, matchCRS)
File "C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\utils.py", line 421, in exportRaster
shutil.copyfile(piped_file, piped_3857)
File "C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Local\Temp\ProtectedAreasDatabaseoftheUnitedStatesPADUSv3001701282171_piped.tif'

Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May 3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
QGIS version: 3.16.15-Hannover Hannover, e7fdad64

Python Path:
C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\HTML_Generator-main
C:/PROGRA1/QGIS311.15/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA1/QGIS311.15/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.15\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.15\bin
C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\GDAL-3.4.0-py3.9-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA1\QGIS311.15\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\go2streetview\res
C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web
C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_resource_sharing
C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis_resource_sharing
C:\Users\jsaf\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis_resource_sharing\ext_libs
.
C:/Users/jsaf/OneDrive/Desktop/Maps/Geology_Geospatial_Data
C:\Users/jsaf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\go2streetview

Comment: A few notes - if you try and add ArcGIS REST services directly to a Mapbox map you will be limited to 1000 or 2000 features depending on the server setup, if they are vector. Raster can be added just fine (albeit it's slow). If vector and the feature limit is OK you can query them as GeoJSON and add them just fine -AI can help you with that. Otherwise you will need to download them all first and add them in as GeoJSON or or another format for your map.